# Updating Images and Render Speed

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

I'm rendering an animated scene in cycles and I noticed that every frame it was being rendered my hdri was being loaded. This doesn't make much sense to me the hdri is static, isn't it a waste of resources to constantly update something static?

It might be a totally stupid question. I have no idea how Blender works on the inside but it seems a waste of resources and time so I was just wondering whether this is a thing that can be "fixed" or is it simply a blender thing that simply needs to exist.

Comment: I think if your camera is moving then it is goint render different parts of the hdri. Maybe it does not load te other parts of the hdri on the frame before?

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Render Properties > Performance > Final Render > Check Persistent Data*